# Bootstrap input and span inside td on the same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem displaying input and span on the same line. They are inside first cell in the table.

What I've already tried is to use form-inline class, but both elements are still displayed in separate lines.

What am I doing wrong?

[Code example from code pen.](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/rYGrZR)

[image]

Source:

```
<table id="tblJEEVUG" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Št. oseb</th>
        <th>Opomba</th>
        <th>Skupina</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr data-ievug_key="170000536">



              <td id="devug_dst" style="width:200px;"><input class="form-control datetimepicker form-inline bounddtp" value="" style="width:70%;">
                <span id="spanOK" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-inline" style="color: green; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; width: 5%;"></span></td>
              <td id="ievug_nop" style="width:50px;"><input class="form-control cbeh-number"></td>
              <td id="cevug_nto"><input class="form-control" value="zdaj pa en komnetar tule notri zapišem jaz"></td>
              <td id="igrop_key">

                <select class="form-control" data-editable="1">
                  <option></option>
                      <option value="100000030">Oddelek za transport</option>
                      <option value="100000029">Catering strežba</option>
                      <option value="100000504" selected="">Catering vodje prireditve</option>
                      <option value="100000748">HKJ-odgovorni kuharji </option>
                      <option value="100000028">HKJ-kuharji </option>

                </select>

              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Izbriši" style="color:red;cursor:pointer;display:block;" onclick="PopUpJEEVUS.RemoveRowJEEVUG(this);"></span>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr data-ievug_key="170000537">



              <td id="devug_dst" style="width:200px;"><input class="form-control datetimepicker form-inline bounddtp" value="15.11.2017 10:30" style="width:70%;">
                <span id="spanOK" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-inline" style="color: green; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; width: 25%;"></span></td>
              <td id="ievug_nop" style="width:50px;"><input class="form-control cbeh-number" value="44"></td>
              <td id="cevug_nto"><input class="form-control" value="transtport pa bom dal en manjši komentar za tale transport sedaj"></td>
              <td id="igrop_key">

                <select class="form-control" data-editable="1">
                  <option></option>
                      <option value="100000030" selected="">Oddelek za transport</option>
                      <option value="100000029">Catering strežba</option>
                      <option value="100000504">Catering vodje prireditve</option>
                      <option value="100000748">HKJ-odgovorni kuharji </option>
                      <option value="100000028">HKJ-kuharji </option>

                </select>

              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Izbriši" style="color:red;cursor:pointer;display:block;" onclick="PopUpJEEVUS.RemoveRowJEEVUG(this);"></span>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr data-ievug_key="170000535">



              <td id="devug_dst" style="width:200px;"><input class="form-control datetimepicker form-inline bounddtp" value="16.11.2017 10:30" style="width:70%;">
                <span id="spanOK" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-inline" style="color: green; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; width: 25%;"></span></td>
              <td id="ievug_nop" style="width:50px;"><input class="form-control cbeh-number" value="44"></td>
              <td id="cevug_nto"><input class="form-control" value="fffffffffffffffffffff"></td>
              <td id="igrop_key">

                <select class="form-control" data-editable="1">
                  <option></option>
                      <option value="100000030">Oddelek za transport</option>
                      <option value="100000029" selected="">Catering strežba</option>
                      <option value="100000504">Catering vodje prireditve</option>
                      <option value="100000748">HKJ-odgovorni kuharji </option>
                      <option value="100000028">HKJ-kuharji </option>

                </select>

              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Izbriši" style="color:red;cursor:pointer;display:block;" onclick="PopUpJEEVUS.RemoveRowJEEVUG(this);"></span>
              </td>

            </tr>



    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: `.form-control` sets `display:block` for your input element - so either overwrite that, or use a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the `float: left;` on input textboxes
Check [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVLjgb) my example

Answer (score 1):

Just add `float:left` to form control class and `margin-right` to make it look good.
https://codepen.io/lionelchris/pen/dZVqoO

Answer (score 1):

Put `display: inline-block` css in form-control and if you are using Bootstrap4, in that case, you can put `.d-inline-block` class in the input.

This will run your code correctly.